# Best approach to build reusable C# data integration assemblies

Tags: powershell, ssis, code-reuse

How have you addressed the issues when building a reuseable suite of C# data integration assemblies? We're a Microsoft shop using Sql Server and C#. We're consolidating a lot of our DB integration code into C# assemblies. In doing so we're hitting a number of common problems.

1. We like the source/destination flexibility of SSIS and the GUI, but
   that environment only (easily) supports cut/paste re-use - unless
   you know different.
2. We could create (console) apps which use standard command line
   parameters and/or config files. In that way we can batch up common
   tasks but we don't have a gui.
3. If we code up a generic GUI to work with our standard parameters
   we're moving into the territory of re-creating SSIS.
4. We could use our C# assemblies through a power shell wrapper.
   However PowerShell is great for developers/admins but not users and
   we're hearing that it's a slower than equivalent SSIS, and we hit
   the GUI issue again.

Our typical integration task will take information from 2 different database sources and a flat file, apply some (really) complex logic and then update a third database.

Comment: Just a thought - how feasible is it to write a C# app that generates and then executes a SSIS package?  I'm not suggesting generating the .xml that consitutes such a package 'manually' - just wondered whether SSIS has a framework for creating packages programatically.

Comment: It can be done http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/03/28/SSIS_3A00_-Building-Packages-Programatically.aspx but that strikes me as one of those 'programmer fun' jobs rather than solving the real problem

Comment: ... also known as "yak shaving."

Comment: @xOn - so that's what I've been doing all this time

Comment: What are you trying to "reuse"?  SSIS has a couple levels of reuse support - package configurations, scripts (with external assemblies), custom tasks and components, ...